# password validation using jquery issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, passwords

I have an app where I am validating the passwords. I have a popup(bootstrap) which lists the rules and they change from X to check based on meeting the conditions. Everything is working fine except one scenario.

I type in the password1 and the check happens and it is fine, then I type in the 2nd password and it is also fine. Then if I move away from the password fields to another and come back to password field, they say it is invalid. But technically they are matching password.(I tried to change the class to glyphicon-ok in both the password fields, but then the issue is reverse)

**password fields**

```
<form:input id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" path="password11" 
    title="Password Check" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" 
    data-content="<span id=&quot;char&quot; class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-remove&quot; style=&quot;color:#FF0004;&quot;></span>10-30chars</li></ul><br>"
    />

    <form:input id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" path="password22" 
        title="Password Check" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" 
        data-content="<span id=&quot;char&quot; class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-remove&quot; style=&quot;color:#FF0004;&quot;></span>Password match</li></ul><br>"
        />
```

**js file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$("input[type=password]").keyup(function(){
    //$("#element").on('keyup change', function ()
    //$("input[type=password]").on('keyup focus focusout change', (function

    $("input[type=password]").keyup(function(){

        if(($("#password1").val().length >= 10) && ($("#password1").val().length <= 30)){
            $("#char").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
            $("#char").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
            $("#char").css("color","#");
        }else{
            $("#char").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
            $("#char").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
            $("#char").css("color","#");
        }



        if($("#password1").val() == $("#password2").val()){
            $("#pwmatch").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
            $("#pwmatch").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
            $("#pwmatch").css("color","#");
        }else{
            $("#pwmatch").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
            $("#pwmatch").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
            $("#pwmatch").css("color","#");
        }
});


});
```

So I need to be able to validate the password and even if I move from that field and come back they should display the right pop-up values(meaning if the 2 passwords match, I should see the check, else X).

Thanks.

Comment: The provided code lacks context. Could please provide a working example? I can only guess, that the markup was taken from a spring project?

Comment: The markup in data-content attribute doesn't make much sense - maybe with more context. However it seems that you want to set the proper id for the content of the second data-content attribute from char to pwmatch

Comment: Maybe this helps as starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/axfakkva/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to create a fiddle(first time), but not successful yet. But the issue I see is inside the form element where I need to define the class as class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove". So when I go out of the password box and come back, the popup is saying as X(glyphicon-remove) since I think it does not have the previous status. Let me know what information you need. In the mean time I will try to get the fiddle working. Thanks again.

Comment: I used this page as my reference - http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/rvear. I put those checks in the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working, though it is not elegant. I just added the whole keyup function to focus function(both are 2 different functions now) and it is working fine now. I tried chaining, but it did not work. But I am fine for now and will check on this later. Thanks.